# Problem in finding the Average of an array in mips

Tags: arrays, sum, mips, average, instructions

I have recently started learning the Mips assembly language and was on its basics. I had a few pronlems in finding the mean of my program in mips. Can someone help me out by explaining to me the instructions used to find out the mean. An example of the code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a sample code. The useful information is being told through comments in the code below. I hope this would be of some help.

.data

arr: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
arrLen: .word 7
avg: .asciiz "\nAverage: "

.text
.globl main

main:

```
la  $t0, arr    #array is stored
lw  $t1, arrLen #array length stored
li  $t2, 0      
li  $t3, 0
```

loop:               #loop for the sum

```
sltiu $t7, $t2, 7   #should be run uptil 7 since its the array length
beq   $t7, $0,  stop    
lw    $t4, ($t0)
addu $t3, $t3, $t4
addiu   $t0, $t0, 4
addiu $t2, $t2, 1
j loop
```

stop:

```
la  $a0, avg
li  $v0, 4
syscall

div $t5, $t3, $t1   #average is taken out using the sum calculated above
move $a0, $t5       #value moved to a0 register to be printed
li $v0, 1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall         #end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .data
```

size:       .word       0
to_store:   .word       0
sum:        .word       0
avg:        .word       0

size_prompt:    .asciiz "Enter number of elements: "
element_prompt: .asciiz "Enter an element: "
msg_space:      .asciiz " "

```
.text
.globl  main
```

main:

```
# Prints prompt
la      $a0,size_prompt
addi    $v0,$0,4
syscall

# Gets input from user
addi    $v0,$0,5
syscall
sw      $v0,size

addi    $t0,$0,0                

# Creates the list
lw      $s0,size                
addi    $t1,$0,4               
mult    $s0,$t1                 
mflo    $t2                     
add     $a0,$t1,$t2
addi    $v0,$0,9
syscall
```

stack:
beq     $t0,$s0,list_sum

```
# prompt user for list element
la      $a0,element_prompt
addi    $v0,$0,4
syscall

# read in element value
addi    $v0,$0,5
syscall
sw      $v0,to_store
lw      $t5,to_store

# push element to stack
addi    $sp,$sp,-4
sw      $t5,0($sp)

addi    $t0,$t0,1           
j       stack

# get sum of array elements
```

list_sum:
beq     $s0,0,average       # at end? if yes, fly
lw      $t6,sum             # get previous sum
lw      $t7,0($sp)          # get next array element value
addi    $sp,$sp,4           # advance array pointer
add     $t6,$t7,$t6         # sum += array[i]
sw      $t6,sum             # store it
addi    $s0,$s0,-1          # bump down the *count*
j       list_sum

average:
lw      $t0,sum             # get the sum

```
# print the sum
li      $v0,1
move    $a0,$t0
syscall

# NOTE/FIX: restore the count value
lw      $s0,size

div     $t0,$s0             # divide by count
mflo    $t0
sw      $t0,avg             # store average

li      $v0,4
la      $a0,msg_space
syscall

# print average
lw      $a0,avg
addi    $v0,$0,1
syscall
```

exit:
li      $v0,10              # exit program
syscall